# what should I write as the argument to Set remove() method if I want to remove ("one", 1) from Set

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, set

I'm learning ***Map interface*** from [Java tutorial oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) and have encountered the following statement:

> The Collection views support element removal in all its many forms —
>   remove, removeAll, retainAll, and clear operations, as well as the
>   Iterator.remove operation.

So I have came up with the following code and tried to use `Collection.remove()` method to remove one of the element, i.e. `("one", 1)`, from `Set sme1`. But I'm not exactly sure what should I write as the argument to `sme1.remove()` method if I want to remove `("one", 1)` from `sme1`.  Could someone please help me out? Thanks in advance for any help!

```
Map<String, Integer> m1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
m1.put("one", 1);
m1.put("two", 2);
m1.put("three", 3);

Set<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> sme1 = m1.entrySet();
System.out.println(sme1);

sme1.remove(?);//what should I write as the argument to sme1.remove() method if I want to remove ("one", 1) from sme1.

System.out.println(m1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't remove from the EntrySet, remove from the map itself, like this:

```
Map<String, Integer> m1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
m1.put("one", 1);
m1.put("two", 2);
m1.put("three", 3);

System.out.println(m1);

m1.remove("one");

System.out.println(m1);
```

You are telling the map to remove the element with the key="one".

This is a much cleaner solution compared to getting the `Set` of all `Map.Entry`'s in the `Map` and calling `Map.Entry.remove()`

As The Java tutorial states, all `Collection`s support the `remove()` operation. In this case, if you want to do a remove using the `Set` of `Map.Entry`, then you need to tell the `Set` which `Map.Entry` to remove. The `remove()` operations invokes the `equals()` method on each entry in the `Collection`. So, you need to pass it a `Map.Entry` to compare to every other `Map.Entry` in order to find the right element to remove.

Doing it this way would look like:

```
Map<String, Integer> m1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
m1.put("one", 1);
m1.put("two", 2);
m1.put("three", 3);

Set<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> sme1 = m1.entrySet();
System.out.println(sme1);

sme1.remove(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Integer>("one",1));

System.out.println(sme1);
```

Not nearly as 'pretty'!

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful advice. May I ask, why did Java Tutorial Oracle mentioned the statement above? I dont seem to get the purpose of this statement. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I updated the answer to give you more clarification and an alternate example.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation!